# How to iterate and access jQuery cookie array with multiple serialise objects

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery cookie array which I was able to access its data as follows:

```
[{"Name":"Ahmad","AdmNo":"ccs/23/001"},
 {"Name":"Aliyu","AdmNo":"dcs/24/002"},
 {"Name":"Alhassan","AdmNo":"dcs/25/003"}]
```

Please! can any one help me with how to iterate through the data and get all the names.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd do better if you opened google and typed "jquery iterate through array". Faster and easier than ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(yourArray, function(key, value) {
    var name = value['Name'];
    var admno = value['AdmNo'];

    // .. do somethign with them here ..

});
```